# How can I add up two or more array elements (numbers)

Tags: javascript

I want to add up all of the element from var string to each other.
I did try this but now I want to do this for each element.

```
var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;
var number = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
var string = number.split(",");
var number1 = string[0];
var number2 = string[1];
var sum = number1 + number2;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(sum);
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "I want to do this for each element"? 

edit: nevermind, I think your title explained it.

Comment: I would like to make an array of the input string ( var number ) wich is something like this : "1,2,3", after that i want to split that by ( var string )
lastly i want to count up all those values to each other

Comment: There has been no activity for some time. Can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce()` and don't forget to cast your `string` into `int`:

```
var number = "1,2,3,4,5"
var sum = number.split(",").reduce(function (total, num) {
    return total + parseInt(num);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do **R. Saban's** way and there are also other ways as well. For example try this:

```
var start = 0; // Using this to add each element in the array starting from 0, look below
var number = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
var string = number.split(",");

string.forEach(function (num) {
  start += parseInt(num);
});

// variable "start" will hold the end result
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for!
Now i would like to have this for - * and / also, by making an variable of an input where values are + , - , * ore /.
Is there any way i can do the same for divide multiply etc ?